# java multithreading synchronized block not working

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

**I am not able to get why I am getting exception with both : class level lock as well as with object level lock in below code :**

It seems object level locking should work here as we are changing and accessing hm(Object) value using different threads, but still we are getting **exception(java.util.ConcurrentModificationException)**.
I tried with all three locking commented in the code.

I know using **Hashtable** or **ConcurrentHashMap** we can resolve this problem, but **I want to know the concept which is missing using HashMap**.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
class A{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("ABCD");
    StringBuilder exception = new StringBuilder("");
    HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    public void change() {
        //synchronized(A.class) {
        //synchronized (this){
        synchronized (hm){
            (this.str).append(Thread.currentThread().getName().toString());
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"::::::"+str);
            hm.put(Thread.currentThread(), Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }
    public void impact() {
        //synchronized(A.class) {
        //synchronized(this) {
        synchronized(hm) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"...Inside impact :::"+hm.get(Thread.currentThread()));
        }
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Inside print :::"+str);
        System.out.println("Inside print :::exception--"+exception);
    }
}
class B extends Thread{
    A a;
    B(A a){
        this.a=a;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Inside B run::"+a.hm);
            a.change();
            a.impact();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            System.out.println(sw.toString());
            a.exception.append(sw.toString());
            try {
                sw.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class C extends Thread{
    A a;
    C(A a){
        this.a=a;
    }
    public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Inside C run::"+a.hm);
        a.change();
        a.impact();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        System.out.println(sw.toString());
        a.exception.append(sw.toString());
        try {
            sw.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
}
public class multiTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    A a = new A();
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++) {
        B b = new B(a);
        C c = new C(a);
        b.start();
        c.start();
    }
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        a.print();  
    }
}
```

Comment: *I am getting exception*: what is the complete stack trace of the exception? Also, your print() method accesses str and exception without any synchronization. And your B thread prints hm outside of any synchronization block. And it uses exception the same way. Same for C. 1. Make fields private. 2. stop using raw types. 3. make sure **every** access to a shared state is synchronized, on the same lock.

Comment: [I downvoted because your question is missing exception details](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/)

Comment: The stacktrace would likely show that problem occurs during `HashMap.toString()` call, from one of the two `println` of `hm`, since those would iterate the map without being protected by `synchronized`.

Comment: @JBNizet Time to go home I think.  Let's pretend I was never here.

Comment: @JBNizet I added exceptions in the exception list :: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException which will be getting added each time we will get exception.

Comment: @JBNizet, **print()** method does not need any synchronization as we are accessing it from main thread only. #Correcting previous comment  **exception** String

Comment: @RVP yes, it does. The main thread has nothing special. It's a thread, like any other thread, and if it accesses shgared state concurrently, then it needs synchronization. Besides, nothing prevents any other thread to use print(), so if you want your class to be thread-safe, then its print() method should be, too.

Comment: @Andreas **stacktrace** :: Thread[Thread-27,5,main]...Inside impact :::Thread[Thread-27,5,main]
Inside print :::exception--java.util.ConcurrentModificationExceptionjava.util.ConcurrentModificationExceptionjava.util.ConcurrentModificationExceptionjava.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: @RVP That is not a stacktrace. Try actually *printing* the stacktrace using `e.printStackTrace()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
System.out.println("Inside B run::"+a.hm);
```

There is sneaky implicit invocation of `a.hm.toString()` here, and that does sneaky iteration of the map's entries; but you aren't synchronizing on anything, so you don't have exclusive access to the hashmap.

Put it in a synchronized block:

```
synchronized (a.hm) {
  System.out.println("Inside B run::"+a.hm);
}
```

(And make `hm` final; and don't use raw types).

Comment: Thanks @Andy_Turner. It seems problem was only because of mentioned println. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @RVP Sounds like you found this answer useful, so you should up-vote it, i.e. click the up-arrow to the left of the answer. Since it also solved your issue, you should click the checkmark too, to accept the answer, so others can see that you question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: @RVP Really? I see no upvote other than mine, and the answer hasn't been accepted, so you've *not* done it already. Still.

Comment: @Andreas, I have done, Can you see is it up from your side? as I am unable to do it twice, tried again after your comment. It was saying Thanks for the feedback..... and now also same.